# "Unterminated template literal" syntax error when literal contains script tag

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, script-tag, template-literals

I'm using ES6 template literals to construct some HTML in strings, and so far it has been working fine.  However, as soon as I try to put the literal text `</script>` in my string the browser throws up and throws the syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal
```

Here is a simple JavaScript sample which throws the error:

```
var str=`
<script>
</script>
`
var pre = document.createElement('pre')
pre.textContent = str
document.body.appendChild(pre)
```

See the above code in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6quwnhwn/).

It appears that what is happening is that it gives up looking for the end literal quote and instead starts treating everything at point as literal HTML, so all the JavaScript after that point is incorrectly treated as HTML, which it is not!

If I replace `script` by *any* other legal HTML tag (and even invalid tags like `scripty`) then it works just fine, so I can't see how this can possibly be a syntax error or a weird case where I think I have typed one character (e.g. the backtick) but instead have typed another that looks almost like it.

I am literally creating a string (to my understand, at compile time), the browser should *not* be attempting to treat it as HTML or in any way parse it. So what gives?

Comment: Some browsers stop interpreting the Javascript on `</SCRIPT>`. Remove it or replace it with `<\/SCRIPT>`.

Comment: (Noting that this is duped all over SO.)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you insert `</script>` inside a script tag, no matter if it's a string in quotes, apostrophes, or even a template literal, it will *always* close the script tag. You have to escape it, for example like that:

```
var str=`
<script>
<\/script>
`
var pre = document.createElement('pre')
pre.textContent = str
document.body.appendChild(pre)
```

However, if you use external script `<script src="url"></script>`, it should work fine without escaping.

Comment: Ah.... for some reason (such as the fact that I can freely put other kinds of quotes inside template quotes) I was thinking that anything inside the template quotes was isolated from the rest of the document.  That indeed fixes it!

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this was what was causing my error, but when I came across your post I was able to get my HTML ES6 template literal to print properly by escaping every close tag.

Comment: Oh. I was thinking I found a major bug in ES6 template literals...

Comment: you can fix that by using a self close tag
```js
const url = 'https://file.js';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<script src="${url}" />`);
```

Comment: I had never come across this before. This was definitely an interesting find. Thank you for this. Do you have any supporting documentation for this?