# How to display a script tag with json content in a code block in html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to display a chunk of code generated dynamically inside a code example block that users can highlight a copy.

The content will change based on user input so it cannot be hardcoded.

This is an example of the content I would like to display inside the block:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "name": "PBOV1 Is a Human De Novo Gene with Tumor-Specific Expression That Is Associated with a Positive Clinical Outcome of Cancer",
  "keywords": "pbov1, tumor-specific, cancer, Cancer, Evolutionary Biology, Immunology",
  "version": "1",
  "url": "https://figshare.com/articles/PBOV1_Is_a_Human_De_Novo_Gene_with_Tumor_Specific_Expression_That_Is_Associated_with_a_Positive_Clinical_Outcome_of_Cancer__/156778",
  "license": ""
}</script>
```

I'm using VueJS and this is the method in progress:

```
makeScript(){
  var str = JSON.stringify(this.metadata, null, 2);
  var script=document.createElement('script');
  script.type='application/ld+json';
  script.text = str;
  this.result = script;
  document.getElementById("resultCode").appendChild(script);
},
```

I've tried "code" and "pre" and all it shows is nothing but the script is there. I think the script is getting compiled and not shown as text, I could be wrong.... I hope that makes sense.

output goes here:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <pre >
    <code id="resultCode">
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/z7j1n2ok/

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Thank you @ChrisG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct the script element.
2. Put it in a new, temporary element.
3. Put the `innerHTML` of the temp element into a text node.
4. Put that text node into the output element.

```js
function makeScript() {
  metadata = {
    "name": "PBOV1 Is a Human De Novo Gene with Tumor-Specific Expression That Is Associated with a Positive Clinical Outcome of Cancer",
    "keywords": "pbov1, tumor-specific, cancer, Cancer, Evolutionary Biology, Immunology",
    "version": "1",
    "url": "https://figshare.com/articles/PBOV1_Is_a_Human_De_Novo_Gene_with_Tumor_Specific_Expression_That_Is_Associated_with_a_Positive_Clinical_Outcome_of_Cancer__/156778",
    "license": ""
  }
  var str = JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2);
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'application/ld+json';
  script.text = str;
  
  p = document.createElement('div');
  p.appendChild(script);
  text = document.createTextNode(p.innerHTML);
  
  document.getElementById("resultCode").appendChild(text);
}

makeScript();
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <pre><code id="resultCode"></code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) in a Vue template.

1. Add a data property (e.g., named "`code`") to your component.

   ```
      data() {
        return {
          code: ''
        }
      }
   ```
2. Edit your template to interpolate that data property:

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
      <pre>
        <code id="resultCode">
          {{code}}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
   ```
3. Set the data property to the desired raw HTML (i.e., the `<script>` block you mentioned in question):

   ```
      methods: {
        setCode() {
          this.code = `
          <script type="application/ld+json">{
            "name": "PBOV1 Is a Human De Novo Gene with Tumor-Specific Expression That Is Associated with a Positive Clinical Outcome of Cancer",
            "keywords": "pbov1, tumor-specific, cancer, Cancer, Evolutionary Biology, Immunology",
            "version": "1",
            "url": "https://figshare.com/articles/PBOV1_Is_a_Human_De_Novo_Gene_with_Tumor_Specific_Expression_That_Is_Associated_with_a_Positive_Clinical_Outcome_of_Cancer__/156778",
            "license": ""
          }<\/script>
          `; // Must escape closing script tag
        }
      }
   ```

   **Note** this method requires escaping the closing `<script>` tag to [avoid a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607932/unterminated-template-literal-syntax-error-when-literal-contains-script-tag).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    code: '',
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.setCode();
  },
  methods: {
    setCode() {
      this.code = `<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "name": "PBOV1 Is a Human De Novo Gene with Tumor-Specific Expression That Is Associated with a Positive Clinical Outcome of Cancer",
  "keywords": "pbov1, tumor-specific, cancer, Cancer, Evolutionary Biology, Immunology",
  "version": "1",
  "url": "https://figshare.com/articles/PBOV1_Is_a_Human_De_Novo_Gene_with_Tumor_Specific_Expression_That_Is_Associated_with_a_Positive_Clinical_Outcome_of_Cancer__/156778",
  "license": ""
}<\/script>`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <pre><code>{{code}}</code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```