# javascript document.write: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

I tried to develop a live code editor.

The code gives the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Where is the problem or is there any solution?

```js
function compile() {
  let htmlContent = document.getElementById('html');
  let cssContent = document.getElementById('css');
  let jsContent = document.getElementById('js');

  let output = document.getElementById('output');

  output = output.contentWindow || output.contentDocument.document || output.contentDocument;

  let doc = output.document;

  doc.open();
  doc.write(
    `<style>${cssContent.value}</style>
                <body>${htmlContent.value}</body>
                <script>${jsContent.value}</script>`
  );
  doc.close();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="html" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea id="css" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea id="js" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="compile()">Run</button>
<iframe id="output"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Closing the script tag**

As pointed out by @Sanmeet in his (deleted) answer, the error is caused by not escaping the backslash in the end script tag: if the html parser decodes a `<script>` tag, it buffers input up to the next `</script>` tag and passes it to the JavaScript compiler. In this case it then treated what was left of the script as text an put it in the body element.

**Reusing variable and class names**

Escaping the end tag to `<\/script>` reveals another problem. Google Chrome does not re-initialize global variable space when  `document.open` is called (as was correct historical practice). Sadly Firefox has altered its behavior to follow suite and no longer re-initializes variables either.

One possible solution is to create a new `iframe` element each time the `run` button is clicked. The example below extends the posted code to create a new `iframe`. If you declare `let`, `const` or `class` identifiers in the JavaScript box, you can now press the run button repeatedly without changing variable and class names.

```js
function compile() {
  let htmlContent = document.getElementById('html');
  let cssContent = document.getElementById('css');
  let jsContent = document.getElementById('js');

  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let replacement = document.createElement('iframe');
  replacement.id = "output";
  output.replaceWith( replacement);
  output = replacement;

  output = output.contentWindow || output.contentDocument.document || output.contentDocument;

  let doc = output.document;

  doc.open();
  doc.write(
    `<style>${cssContent.value}</style>
                <body>${htmlContent.value}</body>
                <script>${jsContent.value}<\/script>`
  );
  doc.close();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="html" cols="30" rows="10"  placeholder="html..."></textarea>
<textarea id="css" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="css..."></textarea>
<textarea id="js" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="js..."></textarea>
<button onclick="compile()">Run</button>
<iframe id="output"></iframe>
```

**Code Snippet Error**

Executing the snippet generates a security error trying to access `doc`. It works as intended in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert  inside a script tag, no matter if it's a string in quotes, apostrophes, or even a template literal, it will always close the script tag. You have to escape it.

```
 doc.write(
  `<style>${cssContent.value}</style>
   <body>${htmlContent.value}</body>
   <script>${jsContent.value}<\/script>`);
```

However, if you use external script , it should work fine without escaping.

More discussion here: ["Unterminated template literal" syntax error when literal contains script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607932/unterminated-template-literal-syntax-error-when-literal-contains-script-tag)